# smartdiagram - text not centered in bubble diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, smartdiagram

I am making the smartdiagram bubble diagram in the MWE below, but it seems pretty obvious to me that the text in the black bubble on the right is not centered at all...

While the same text in other bubbles seems pretty well centered, there is much less space on the left of the word than on the right for the last entry in the black circle.

While it is a minor problem, I was wondering why this happens and if there is a way to solve it. Many thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
    calc,
    fadings,
    shadows,
    shapes.arrows,
    shapes.symbols
}

\usepackage{xparse}
\edef\RestoreEndlinechar{%
    \endlinechar=\the\endlinechar\relax
}
\endlinechar=-1
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\RestoreEndlinechar

\tikzset{bubble node/.append style={
        draw=none, opacity=0.5
    }
}




\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{
    distance text center bubble=0.5cm,
    bubble center node size=3cm,
    bubble node size=3cm,
    distance center/other bubbles=1cm,
    bubble center node font=\LARGE,
    bubble node font=\LARGE,
    bubble center node color=magenta,
    set color list = {yellow, pink, blue, green, black}
}%
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{%
    key\\word,
    another,
    another,
    another,
    another,
    another
}%


\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: figure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that adding a `%` after last word the problem is solved:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
    calc,
    fadings,
    shadows,
    shapes.arrows,
    shapes.symbols
}

\usepackage{xparse}
\edef\RestoreEndlinechar{%
    \endlinechar=\the\endlinechar\relax
}
\endlinechar=-1
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\RestoreEndlinechar

\tikzset{bubble node/.append style={
        draw=none, opacity=0.5
    }
}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{
    distance text center bubble=0.5cm,
    bubble center node size=3cm,
    bubble node size=3cm,
    distance center/other bubbles=1cm,
    bubble center node font=\LARGE,
    bubble node font=\LARGE,
    bubble center node color=magenta,
    set color list = {yellow, pink, blue, green, black}
}%
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{%
    key\\word,
    another,
    another,
    another,
    another,
    another% <---- This white space was the problem!
}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: It indeed does solve the problem! Aaah I will never get used to using %...