# smartdiagram and other packages

Tags: smartdiagram

I use the code from

[smartdiagram - text not centered in bubble diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343176/smartdiagram-text-not-centered-in-bubble-diagram)

in my enviroment.

But I get an other picture.

[image: on the right the colors are not mixed]

Does someone knows why? Perhelps a package which changed definitions?

Comment: Looks like a missing `opacity=0.5`-setting (or it is overwriten later with a fill-option?). Can you post your code! Without it is difficult to guess what your problem is.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I get exactly the same output that Ignasi posted together with his solution. Is your TeX distribution up - to -date?

Comment: The code is very big with many files. I tried a day to solve by deleting package and so on. I get no solution. Perhaps the Color and xcolor package.

Comment: opacity=0.5-setting is in the code. Where an after what should I look? How does such a fill-option looks like?

Comment: My TeX distribution is up - to -date? I also get the "Right" Output like you can see in the left of the Picture. But not in my environment.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.